# Documentation of flow (flowtype) errors

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

I have repeatedly run into flow type errors that I didn't find any information on through duckduckgo or google.

One recent example:

```
    statics of MyView [1] is not a polymorphic type.
      6│   navigation: any,
      7│ }
      8│
 [1]  9│ export default class MySubView extends MyView <Props> {
     10│   succesfullyChanged = () => {
     11│     this.setState({
     12│       loading: false,
```

MyView:

```
type State = {
  \\ lots of state
};


export default class MyView extends React.Component <{}, State> {
  \\..
};
```

If anyone could point me in the direction where I could find more information on how to make `MyView` a polymorphic type, that would be great.

I am aware of the [flow docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/). They do however not show up when searching for specific errors.

I am looking for something like the extensive [flow documentation](https://eslint.org/) where each rule/error is documented with examples.

Edit:
I found the documentation on [generyc types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/) which seem to be polymorphic types. It now seems like flow mistakes my `<Props>` for a generic type?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't declared `MyView` properly, but it's hard to say without more information. I'd also say that subclassing a React component is a bad idea in general. Use composition, not inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The view seems to work. Only flow is complaining.

Comment: Totally, there's lots of code that will run but make Flow unhappy. You'll have to show us how `MyView` is defined for this to be answerable.

Comment: thanks for the help. I added the definition of `MyView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `MyView` is something that you expect subclass and have different `Props` on, you need to make it polymorphic like this:

```
export default class MyView<Props> extends React.Component<Props, State> {
```

which declares that the `MyView` class is polymorphic and can accept a set of properties that just gets passed through to `React.Component`. What you had with

```
export default class MyView extends React.Component<{}, State> {
```

declares it as a class with props limited to an empty object, so it has no usable `.props`. If that *was* what you wanted, you'd do `class MySubView extends MyView {` because there wouldn't be any properties to adjust.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on your comment on the original question that it is a bad Idea to use inheritance with react native components? Are there side effects I need to consider when doing so or what do you see as the problem?

Comment: I'd refer to the main React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html